# How to connect two tables to form an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have two tables: *points* and *videos*. I only want a video to show if the logged in user hasn't already been awarded points for watching that particular video.

The `points db` structure: id, special, user and points.

Special is the unique id of the video.

The `videos db` structure: id, title, points, src, photo, token, special.

There are multiple pages on this site. Token tells the video which page that video is ssigned to. Special is a special id for only that video and correlates to the special in the `points db`

--

This is the SQL Query I basicially want to say: `$db->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE token='$id' AND num_rows OF user='$user' AND special='$special' == 0 FROM TABLE points");`

Now I know this is not the proper format to write SQL Queries, but this is what I want in human. How do I translate this request to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join videos, points tables using the *special* column.

```
select count(*) from videos a join points b on (a.special = b.special) where b.user = '$user' and a.token = '$id';
```

This count will be 0 if the user has not watched the video.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I fetch the results from this SQL Query? From the `video` db, I want to get the title, photo,points,src & special. Previously, I did this by `$special_video = $fetch_videos["special"];`. How does this change with the new SQL query?